# Add is_moderator to the /me endpoint

Tags: feature-request, api, users

There's [an endpoint](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me) for getting information about a user - called `/me`. I can get a number of fields from it, including `is_staff`, which, presumably, indicates if a user is an SE staff member.

Could `is_moderator` also be added, where it returns `true` if the user is a moderator on the `site` specified? It's occasionally useful to do this, such as for applications where, for example, I'd like staff and diamond mods to have some privileges that non-mods don't get.

Comment: The information you're looking for is available from either the [`/me/associated`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-associated-users) or [`/users/moderators`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/moderators) endpoints.